# PayPal Subscription with Monthly and Yearly Cycle

Tags: paypal

I am building a shopping cart for monthly packages and domain name registration yearly costs. What is the best way of having this so that PayPal takes the first lump sum payment (total of both items for the first time order) but then only charges the monthly package on a monthly basis and the domain registration yearly basis moving forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine two simultaneous cycles (every 1 MONTH and 1 YEAR) into a single PayPal subscription plan.  You would need to have the user check out with two separate subscriptions for that.